# Can tesseract be trained to recognize and process formatted documents?

Tags: tesseract

I tried tesseract with some standard text images. It's great. Now can I teach tesseract to understand the format of a document? I mean lets take a wedding invitation of an invitation card. There could be a square box in which the time and place might have been written. If say there are only three formats possible for all wedding invitations (I want to process) can I teach tesseract to somehow see this? Or should I somehow "extend" the code to do that myself?

Answer (score 1):

As i know tesseract is not the best in layout analysis. In my test scenarias I had problems getting good results, if the images contained some not-text parts, like layouts. There are lots of other commercial OCR libraries or commercial products available, which also can handle layout analysis in a good way. If you want to use an free open source library, like tesseract, I would recommend to split your program into following parts:

1. Text detection of your Region of interest (image part which only contains text, can also be more sub images)
2. Handle these images forward as input for tesseract, disabled all layout analyses in tesseract and use it only for character recognition,

For this purpose I would use the free open source library openCv in c++ for the text detection part.

Regarding you question, if tesseract can detect the type of  wedding card automatically:

It can perform some layout analysis and do character detection afterwards, but it will do the same processes for all types of images. As I know it is only possible to handle tesseract an input image and a rectangle, where tesseract should perform ocr, but as I know this option is only available when using tesseract with c++ code, and not via the command line.